# ggplot - label as calculated increase (%)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have developed a ggplot graph but now I am trying to add calculated label which shows increase in % year-on-year?

My data frame is very simple (result of aggregate from the main dataset)

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Year    : int  2011 2012 2013 2014
 $ TotalPay: num  71744 74113 77611 75466
```

I have a code for my graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d1, aes(x=Year, y=TotalPay)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
labs(x="Year", y="Average Total Pay ($)")
```

and now trying to use stat_bin for lables? The calculation is Actual Year - Previous Year * 100%. I have this but not sure how to fill percent ()

```
stat_bin(aes (labels = paste("Total Pay" = ,scales::percent(())), vjust = 1, geom = "TexT")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would compute the change beforehand and then plot it with `geom_text`:

```
library(dplyr)
d1 <- data.frame(Year=2011:2014,TotalPay=c(71744,74112,77611,65466))
d1 <- mutate(d1,change=(TotalPay - lag(TotalPay))/lag(TotalPay))

ggplot(d1, aes(x=Year, y=TotalPay)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  labs(x="Year", y="Average Total Pay ($)") +
  geom_text(data=d1[-1,],aes(label = scales::percent(change)), vjust = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I was playing with it, but I had no idea what OP really wanted.