# ggplot: add percentages to a bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say we create a bar graph where we want to show the percentage falling into a given category. I'm thinking of survey data and showing how many people responded to A, B, or C and doing this WITHOUT having to change the data.

Sample code:

```
data(mtcars)
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(hp))+
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), binwidth = 25) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

Now how do I add the percentage labels? I've tried a lot of different approaches and seen a lot of what people have posted, but have not had any luck.

Comment: what do you mean by *percentage labels*? Where are you trying to place them?

Comment: At the top of each bar graph. So for example, category 1 has 10 respondents out of 100, so the label should be 10% and slightly above the bar.

I don't want a histogram because the response levels will be pre-set, sort of like a factor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558129/ggplot-label-as-calculated-increase there should be several similar questions

Comment: yes, many exmaples - http://stackoverflow.com/q/11653268/5977215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way: you could use `stat_bin` with `geom="text"`:

```
data(mtcars)
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(hp))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), binwidth = 25) + 
  stat_bin(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), 
               label=scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), 
           geom="text", binwidth = 25, vjust=-.2)
```

[image]